# Inner join returning all the values from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

I have two tables, TableA and TableB,

```
TableA
-------------------------------------------------
Date        ORDERNUMBER PARTNUMBER  ID
--------------------------------------------------------
2017-08-16  ORD001      PART001     1         
2017-08-16  ORD002      PART002     2         
2017-08-16  ORD003      PART003     3         
2017-08-16  ORD004      PART003     4   


TableB
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Date        ORDERNUMBER PARTNUMBER  ID       PARTTYPE
---------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-08-16  ORD006      PART006     6           BAG
2017-08-16  ORD007      PART007     7           BAG
2017-08-16  ORD008      PART008     8           BAG
2017-08-16  ORD009      PART009     9           PACK
2017-08-16  ORD0010     PART0010    10          PACK
```

Now I want to get the values from `TableB` where `OrderNumber` is not in `TableA` and `PARTTYPE` is 'PACK'.

To do that I try doing inner join,But this brings back following result.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B WIT(NOLOCK) ON A.ORDERNUMBER != B.ORDERNUMBER 
                                AND B.PARTTYPE = 'PACK'
WHERE A.Date = '16 AUG 2017'
```

Result of the join is everything:

```
Date        ORDERNUMBER PARTNUMBER  ID      Date        ORDERNUMBER PARTNUMBER  ID      PARTTYPE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-08-16  ORD001      PART001     1           2017-08-16O RD009       PART009     9           PACK
2017-08-16  ORD002      PART002     2           2017-08-16O RD009       PART009     9           PACK
2017-08-16  ORD003      PART003     3           2017-08-16O RD009       PART009     9           PACK
2017-08-16  ORD004      PART003     4           2017-08-16O RD009       PART009     9           PACK
2017-08-16  ORD001      PART001     1           2017-08-16O RD0010      PART0010    10          PACK
2017-08-16  ORD002      PART002     2           2017-08-16O RD0010      PART0010    10          PACK
2017-08-16  ORD003      PART003     3           2017-08-16O RD0010      PART0010    10          PACK
2017-08-16  ORD004      PART003     4           2017-08-16O RD0010      PART0010    10          PACK
```

I also tried a subquery, but I know this is wrong:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA 
WHERE ORDERNUMBER NOT IN (SELECT ORDERNUMBER 
                          FROM TableB 
                          WHERE PARTTYPE = 'PACK')
```

I should be using NOT IN and JOINS together, but just could not think of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to Get the values from TableB where OrderNumber is not in TableA and PARTTYPE is 'PACK'.

This basically seems fairly basic using `not exists`:

```
select b.*
from tableb b
where parttype = 'PACK' and
      not exists (select 1 from tablea a where a.ordernumber = b.ordernumber);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do a left join here:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM TableB b
LEFT JOIN TableA a
    ON a.ordernumber = b.ordernumber
WHERE
    a.ordernumber IS NULL AND
    b.parttype = 'PACK'
```